# If input is not what was expected but is handled correctly is it valid?

Tags: testing

I'm doing software testing on a web service and I'm wondering, if the web service takes a zip code and returns coordinates of the zip code. if I input 99999, which is not a zip code, but the system doesn't crash, it just replies with a 0 on both coordinates, is that considered to be an invalid input? I'm not really sure since it is not crashing the system, it means it can handle the input, so does it make the input valid or is it still invalid due that 99999 is not a zip code?

Comment: How did you get the coordinates? Are you using any library? What language do you use?

Comment: @YMD: None of that is relevant to the question asked.

Comment: What colour underwear are you wearing? What time of the day is it in your timezone? What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow? :-)

Comment: I do not have that info, it is not my webservice, its just a public webservice, but how the others pointed out, that is irrelevant for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends *entirely* on what the specification for the web service states.

For example:

- If it states it returns 0 on invalid input, it's working fine - move along.
- If it states you should only provide valid input, you're breaking the contract and it is free to do whatever it wishes. Move along.
- If it *doesn't* state what it will do for invalid input, it is also allowed to do whatever it wishes. It's *usual* to follow the principle of least astonishment but by no means mandatory.

This last point is an important one: a true bug exists only when software doesn't work as documented. Far too many people think it's a bug when software doesn't work as they expect but, in reality, that's an implementation decision.

That decision *may* be bad if, for example, you cannot tell the difference between an "error" condition and valid input but that's probably not the case here. Assuming those coordinates are latitude/longitude, `0/0` is in the middle of the Atlantic, some 600km from the nearest major landmass. So it's unlikely any zip code would resolve to that co-ordinate.

Having said that, any decent web service *should* document allowable inputs and state what will happen if the contract is broken. It's possible the one you're using does this (we cannot tell since we don't know which one you're using), you may need to search for it.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define invalid? One of Google's definitions is:

> (of computer instructions, data, etc.) not conforming to the correct format or specifications.

According to this definition, it is invalid. And it is producing an invalid answer.

---

However, if it is your web service, and if this is expected behavior (made on purpose to prevent a crash and presenting the user with an obviously incorrect answer), then I wouldn't consider it invalid. In a way this is "expected input" — it is a safeguard against user error, which you should always add into your code.

But if this is the case, then I'd suppose you take a different approach to warning the user of an incorrect user.